# Usability Principles in Mobile Responsive Design

Tags: css, usability, responsive-design

I am currently working on a mobile adaptation of a site and I am curious as to what peoples generic rules are about usability issues such as button and link sizes.

For example my site looks slightly different on an iPad (no change whatsoever on landscape display), but once the screen gets less than 515px I have then changed the link font-sizes to 150% and added extra margin between buttons. My reason for this is that with all good usability on smaller screens, the buttons are larger and clearer and therefore easier to use. The things is with most rules I find myself constantly debating which size screens I should apply these rules to and which sizes I should overlook. For example should I increase the links sizes on the iPad screens too?!

Additionally does anyone have any good set of practices they keep to when designing for certain device sizes?

Comment: there's a separate UX site full of UX experts at ux.stackexchange.com

Comment: You might also find some ideas over on http://ux.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an interesting article about responsive design:

http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-with-css3-media-queries

Don't forget, that it's not just readability that's important. People usually use small devices with their fingers, so as long as the 'hit area's' of your elements is good then half of your usability issues have already been addressed.

I'd like to be more help, but this really is a bit of a 'suck it and see' type of deal. There's no one size fits all solution.

Good luck.

Comment: That was my main thought really, because after all people still use their fingers on iPads, so why not design to that? I was wondering at what size screen the 'clumsy factor' takes over and finger size becomes priority in design?